# Can't figure out which projector fits these features

Tags: projector

What I need:

- reasonable resolution (not 640x480, maybe 1024x768 minimum, but I'm willing to budge on this)
- long life, no need to change parts
- connects to a standard computer VGA out

What I don't need

- SD/USB port
- speakers
- color depth
- absolute smoothness
- portability
- HDMI video input
- S-video input
- any other sort of input than VGA

In other words, minimally I need to be able to project in grayscale and without worrying about changing a bulb. So which flavor of digital projector should I be buying?

Comment: What type of environment will this be used in?  Does it need to be portable?

Comment: I wrote that it didn't.

Comment: I see that now.

Answer (score 1):

I would look on Ebay and Craigslist since your requirements would be met by most projectors produced in the last 10+ years. Find one that suits you, and invest in a spare bulb (or two) while you're at it, since you might be buying a used item.

Also, check out Slickdeals for clearance items, such as this BenQ DLP projector that meets your requirements: http://slickdeals.net/forums/showthread.php?t=3634482